# Associativity of product of ideals

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals

Let $A$ and $B$ be ideals of a ring $R$. Define the product of ideals as $AB= \Bigg \{ \displaystyle \sum_{k=1}^n a_k b_k \mid a_k \in A, b_k \in B, n \in \mathbb{N} \Bigg \}$. Is there an easy way to show that this product is associative, i.e., $(AB)C=A(BC)$? And in this case can we say that $(AB)C=A(BC)=ABC:=\Bigg \{ \displaystyle \sum_{k=1}^n a_k b_k c_k \mid a_k \in A, b_k \in B, c_k \in C, n \in \mathbb{N} \Bigg \}$?

Comment: Essentially, this is a consequence of the associativity of multiplication in the ring. I have supplied a detailed explanation below. I'm not sure that there's any easier way to see it, but intuitively, it just amounts to the fact that $(ab)c = abc = a(bc)$ for any elements $a \in A,$ $b \in B,$ and $c \in C.$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By definition, we have that $$(AB)C = \{x_1 c_1 + \cdots + x_n c_n \,|\, n \geq 1, \, x_1, \dots, x_n \in AB, \text{ and } c_1, \dots, c_n \in C\}.$$ Considering that each of the $x_i$ is of the form $x_i = a_{i1} b_{i1} + \cdots + a_{ik} b_{ik}$ for some integer $k \geq 1,$ it follows that $(AB)C \subseteq ABC$ because each of the elements of $(AB)C$ belongs to $ABC.$ Conversely, any product of the form $abc$ for some elements $a \in A,$ $b \in B,$ and $c \in C$ belongs to $(AB)C$ because it can be written as $x_1 c_1$ for $x_1 = ab$ and $c_1 = c,$ hence for any integer $n \geq 1$ and any elements $a_1, \dots, a_n \in A,$ $b_1, \dots, b_n \in B,$ and $c_1, \dots, c_n \in C,$ the sum $a_1 b_1 c_1 + \cdots + a_n b_n c_n$ belongs to $(AB)C.$ Consequently, we have that $(AB)C = ABC.$ But the analogous argument can be made for $A(BC),$ hence we have that $(AB)C = ABC = A(BC).$